# Want to Know alternate Solution of excel2img for linux in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, linux

As we Know excel2img is used to convert excel sheet to image in Windows Only. But i want to convert excel to image on linux server. I already use asposecells (using JVM) but i got half sheet image(i.e in 20 columns i got only 5 column) instead of whole sheet (with 20 columns).

Comment: You might want to show us some code. If Asposecells, whatever it is, works otherwise, maybe we could help you with making it show all the cells you need.

Comment: @AKX https://blog.aspose.com/2021/05/28/convert-excel-to-image-in-python/   i follow the same code where i am unable to take complete screenshot .